# Lyrics for "Into the flow" from 1984 movie "Heavenly Bodies"

Tags: lyrics

I can't find the lyrics for the song [*Into the flow*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bPKVRimJIM) from the 1984 movie [*Heavenly bodies*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087399/).

This song is [credited](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087399/soundtrack?ref_=tt_ql_trv_7) to the Canadian [new wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_wave_music) band [*Boys Brigade*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boys_Brigade_(band)), but very little information is available about them or this song.

I tried searching for the lyrics on Google but no hits turned up.

Can anyone help me identify the entire lyrics for the song? Here is what I have identified so far:

> i feel it all ??? I feel my life I feel my life
>
> I feel it all like a river flows I feel my life I feel my life
>
> Into the flow like a river to the see Into the flow and forever to be
>   free I feel my ???
>
> With no resistance to the motion I feel my life I ?? watch the river
>   flow
>
> Into the flow like a river to the sea Into the flow and forever to be
>   free I feel my world going round and round My mind ???
>
> ?? to you ?? to me ?? to everybody
>
> ?? to you ?? to me ?? to everybody
>
> I feel it all going round and round I see my life I see my life
>
> Into the flow when a river meets the sea Into the flow where forever
>   to be free I feel my world going round and round

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm able to fill in the parts up to "My mind...", which is unclear to me as well. I've also corrected a few words, like "go" instead of "going", "sea" instead of "the sea", etc. Here's my attempt:

> I feel it all go round and round,
>   I feel my life, I feel my life, 
>   I feel it all like a river flows,
>   I feel my life, I feel my life,
>   Into the flow like a river to sea,
>   Into the flow and forever to be free,
>   I feel my world go round and round
>   *wooahh aaaayyy ooohhh*
>
> With no resistance to the motion,
>   I feel my life,
>   I sit and watch the river flow,
>   I feel my life, I feel my life,
>   Into the flow like a river to sea,
>   Into the flow and forever to be free,
>   I feel my world go round and round,
>   My mind want to know all (the) time
>   Who'd to you, who'd to me, who'd to everybody (2)
>
> *When I ??? we move into the flow*
>
> I feel it all go round and round,
>   I see my life, I see my life,
>   Into the flow where the river meets the sea,
>   Into the flow where forever to be free,
>   I feel my world go round and round
>   *wooahh aaaayyy ooohhh*